# Не работает слайдер от яндекса

Tags: javascript, html, css

Нашел слайдер от яндекса, который у них на главной используется на моб. устройствах. Ссылка на гитхаб: https://github.com/yandex-ui/yaTouchSlider

Проблема в том, что он 5 мин назад работал на локалке, теперь перестал. Никаких ошибок, код тот же, тупо перекидываю папку на раб. стол и открываю файл index.html - ничего. Ошибка явно не в слайдере, ибо работал исходник 5 минут назад. Кто может подсказать, в чем может быть дело?

Comment: Клонировал, запустил на эмуляции мобильного, никаких проблем ...

Comment: Тут не угадаешь что именно отвалилось у вас т.к. у меня тоже запустилось без проблем и живет. Попробуйте разные браузеры и т.п. Ну или чтобы совсем убедиться - проверьте вкладку network что файлы все таки "присутсвуют" и пройдитесь дебагером по коду. Если код срабатывает, но ничего нет на экране - тогда уже не знаю что посоветовать =)

Comment: @alexoander сделал уже все не раз) все окей, все работает, 0 ошибок в консоли, в нетворке показано, что все загрузилось

Comment: попробуй кэш в броузере почистить, у меня подобная мистика была, помогло, авось и тебе поможет)